# class/id for data.frame cell using knitr

Tags: html, r, dataframe, datatables, knitr

I want to give some of the entries of my data.frame a special id or class, that I can use it later in html after making an html table out of the data.frame with knitr. Is it possible? I intend to use this later with jquery-datatables for special formatting.

Comment: Yes it is possible to add a column to your data.frame.

Comment: I'm not aware of such an R package yet, but it does not sound like a terribly difficult problem. You can submit a pull request to me if you want to tackle it: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/table.R

Comment: If you tell me what pull request, I do. Maybe there is a probability even to dicide which id out of a set should be assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to add a new column to your data.frame. You might try something like:

```
mydf$newID <- seq(nrow(mydf))
```

Or

```
mydf <- transform(mydf, newID = seq(nrow(mydf))
```

And many others...

Or using the data.table library

```
mydt[,newID:=.I]
```

Comment: sorry for the missunderstanding. A already have a data.frame. Now I want to tell html, that some of its entries have a speicial id or class in html. For example a entry should "generate" a html tbale entry like <td class="test">some data</td>.